# routing issue using jquery in php laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i just went i have create project in php laravel and if i am on main page url like https://www.solhut.com/msbooks and click on button jquery  action performed and routing the function in web.php file. if same class button are call from other url like https://www.solhut.com/msbooks/teacher/35/awais-bhatti and click on add button jquery action performed but not routing function call by jquery.

Custom.js file:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_in_cart", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (readCookie("userID") != null) {
         var product_id = $(this).data("value");

         $.post(base_url + '/app/msbooks/weberp_api.php?mask=msbooks&tag=add_user_cart_item', {
             intUserID: readCookie("userID"),
             intItemID: product_id,
             dblItemQty: 1,
             strItemRemarks: '',
         }, function (response) {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
             if (response['status'] == 1) { // Data Added to Cart
                 **renderCart();**
             } else {
                 alert(response['message']);
             }
         });
     } else {
         location.href = `${redirect_url}/login`;
     }
 });


function renderCart() {
 $.get("rendercart", function (data) {
     $("#cartList").empty();
     var total = 0;
     $("#cart-total").html(data.data.length);
     
     $.each(data['data'], function (i, item) {
         var html = "<li>\n" +
             "                    <div class=\"shopping-cart-img\">\n" +
             "                        <a href=\"#\"><img alt=\"Nest\"\n" +
             "                                                               src=\"" + item.item.strImageThumbnail + "\"/></a>\n" +
             "                    </div>\n" +
             "                    <div class=\"shopping-cart-delete\">\n" +
             "                        <a href=\"#\" class=\"cartItemDel\" data-pid=\"" + item.item.intID + "\"><i class=\"fi-rs-cross-small\"></i></a>\n" +
             "                    </div>\n" +
             "                    <div class=\"shopping-cart-title\">\n" +
             "                        <h4><a href=\"#\">" + item.item.strDesc + "</a></h4>\n" +
             "                        <h4><span>" + item.dblItemQty + " × </span>" + item.item.strUOM + " " + item.item.dblSalePrice + "</h4>\n" +
             "                    </div>\n" +
             "                </li>";
         $("#cartList").append(html);
         
         total += item.item.dblSalePrice * item.dblItemQty
     });
     $(".cartTotal").text("Rs " + total);
 });
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/rendercart', function() {
    $BASE_URL = env('BASE_URL');
    $MASK = env('MASK');
    return Http::get("{$BASE_URL}/app/msbooks/weberp_api.php?mask={$MASK}&tag=get_user_cart&intUserID={$_COOKIE['userID']}")->json();
})->name("rendercart");
```